# 403 when serving images from outside of the project folder spring boot v3.0.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm saving my images in a folder which is **outside of my spring boot project folder**.But when I try to serve the images like `http://localhost:8080/image.ext`, **I get**

> Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view
> this page. HTTP ERROR 403

**Things that I tried**

**1-application.properties**

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/path/to/my/folder/images/
```

**2-Creating a Configuration Handler. I tried with this as well `public class ServeStaticConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport`**

```
@Configuration
public class ServeStaticConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public  void serveStaticResourceHAndler(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/home/path/to/my/folder/images/");
    }
}
```

**2.1-If I use `@override` at the top of above `serveStaticResourceHAndler()` I get the following**

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

**3-I tried by putting `serveStaticResourceHAndler()` in the *main* `@SpringBootApplication` file. But no use**

**4-I tried by putting the `image path` in my `SecurityConfig` file. And when I try to serve like this `http://localhost:8080/home/path/to/my/folder/images/image.ext` I get `Endpoint not found`**

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();

    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/home/path/to/my/folder/images/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(
                    jwtAuthFilter,
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    return http.build();
  }
```

**5-I tried by putting `root`, `.requestMatchers("/**")` instead of `/home/path/to/my/folder/images/**`. But even then no use.**

**6-I'm using `Linux`. So I even checked the permissions for my images folder and even permissions for images themselves.**

**It would be a great help If someone provides a working solution according to new rules of spring boot v3.0.2. And tells me what I'm doing wrong here**

Comment: hi :) so your main mistake is "unsecuring" `/home/path/to/my/folder/images/**` - this is a *local* path and (hopefully ) not known to "the web" at all...

Comment: by doing `spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/path/to/my/folder/images/` you map this (server local) folder to the (spring-boot-default) *web* path: `/**` ([`spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.static-path-pattern)

Comment: assume you have `foo.jpg` and `bar.gif` in your (mentioned) folder, then `requestMatchers("/foo.jpg", "/bar.gif").permitAll()` would be "more correct" (but still to be tested..regarding "ant vs mvc")

Comment: And if I have 100+ files in the mentioned folder. Then I have to provide every file name in `requestMatcher`?

Comment: no, you just need to 1. `spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/path/to/my/folder/` (! without images!, with only relevant content/to be exposed) 2. You have already a folder named `images` inside. with 3. `.requestMatchers(toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()` you permit all access to (local) `/home/path/to/my/folder/images` (..and `./js/`, and `./css/` ...)

Comment: Ok I'm going to try this.

Comment: yes, please try!  "not found" sounds strange, but better than "forbidden"!:)

Comment: Yes I already have enough of 403s with spring boot.But that Not found, I must be missing something from your answer

Comment: When I use `http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    ,toStaticResources().at("/home/path/to/my/folder/images/**" /*,...*/))
            .permitAll()`. It says `Cannot resolve method 'at(String)'`. And in `application.properties` I changed it like this `spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/path/to/my/folder`

Comment: Or even with `toStaticResources().at("/home/path/to/my/folder/images/**")..`

Comment: `requestMatchers()` takes `strings` if i'm not mistaken...

Comment: 1. Request matchers is for *servlet* requests/paths (not for local file system...the *only* link to local file system is in `spring.web.resources.static-locations`... so forget about `/home/...` in your security (*servlet*!) configuration.

Comment: 2. You are only partially not mistaking... (Overloads!)

Comment: Regarding syntax: you can chain/combine `requestMatchers()` freely (but consistently): e.g `.requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",                     "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll().requestMatchers(...)......`

Comment: `anyRequest()` (e.g.) retuns the same (type of) object as `requestMatchers(...)` does (thus can be chained;)

Comment: But you can predict the problem when you do `anyRequest()` (more/-st general) *before* (more precise) `requestMatchers()`!? (Correct: 1st match wins, anyRequest() would always, the more precise never match)

Comment: This is current situation `http.authorizeHttpRequests()
              .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                      "/v3/api-docs/**")
              .permitAll().requestMatchers(toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
              .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()` with  `spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/home/path/to/my/folder/` , now when I try `http://localhost:8080/images/image.ext` I get `Endpoint not found`.

Comment: And with `8080/image.ext` I get `403`. I think I'm miss understanding you in someway

Comment: And one thing more If there's no use for `/home/...` in servelte than what you were trying to explain me with this `toStaticResources().at("/foo/bar/**" /*,...*/ )`, in your answer?

Comment: No, actually "this current situation"  sounds correct.. but: "endpoint not found" is strange...403 on the other hand is consistent/seems ok... I'll post a complete sample to github

Comment: Why not directly like `8080/image.ext` or at root?

Comment: And we know that it is `unsecured way` then what is the secured way actually?

Comment: here is the repo: https://github.com/xerx593/soq75696096

Answer (score 1):

1. To use external static resources in a spring-boot-web application, we *only* need (`application.properties`):

   ```properties
   spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/path/to/resources
   ```

   [`spring.web.resources.static`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.web.resources.static-locations)

   > Locations of static resources.
   >
   > Defaults to `classpath:[/META-INF/resources/, /resources/, /static/, /public/]`.

   (for simplicity i just replaced, but we can also combine/have multiple (external+internal) locations)
2. To permit them for/exclude them from Authorization, *best* is:

   a. Use [`toStaticResources()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/PathRequest.html#toStaticResources()):

   ```java
   @Configuration
   class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      return http
          .authorizeHttpRequests(
              (requests) -> requests
                  .requestMatchers(
                    toStaticResources().atCommonLocations() // !
                  ).permitAll() 
                  // ...
          )
          .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
          // ...
          .build();
    }
   }
   ```

   b. With described setup, all content (relatively) from `/path/to/resources` which complies with following structure/paths/matchers :

   - `/images/**`
   - `/css/**`
   - `/js/**`
   - `/webjars/**`
   - `/favicon.*` resp. `/*/icon-*`

   will be served unsecured. (see [`StaticResourceLocation`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/StaticResourceLocation.java))

Tested with [3.0.4](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,thymeleaf,security,devtools) (sry, but confident that it holds for 3.0.2 as well;)

Alternatively to [`atCommonLoactions()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/StaticResourceRequest.html), we can also issue (more selectively) `toStaticResources().at("/foo/bar/**" /*,...*/ )`.

Advantages of this approach:

- Consideration of (all,current,web and mvc relevant) `application.properties` (also multiple locations)
- No need to re-/mistype (i.e. duplicate) patterns
- No worries regarding "ant vs mvc matchers"!;)
- ...

[Github demo](https://github.com/xerx593/soq75696096) ("external folder" is in same repository and is referred *relatively* (assuming working directory is repository root (as documented), it works neat)!)